# Was Nietzsche's project a complete failure?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism

It seems that Nietzsche's project was an attempt to prepare the earth for some kind of higher being, the [overman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9Cbermensch), whether or not that was himself. But a century later it seems we have no overman. Was his mistake to think that mankind has anything meaningful beyond itself, in his specific targeting of morality, or something else?

Perhaps events today are not conducive to the existence of people like Beethoven or Goethe, whatever Nietzsche found admirable in them, "virtue" or talent etc., and this is the minimum necessary for Nietzsche's genealogy to work? That e.g. culture is too mundane etc..

Comment: I actually think that his concept of last man is a failure is well. At least for me as a proponent of psychological egoism.

Comment: that's nice @rus9384 perhaps it didn't occur to you that your peers are untermensch!!!

Comment: Well, there are weak people. But everyone seeks pleasure, I believe. Just some people have value long-term pleasure over short-term. And people who value latter also can be artists. Anyway, by the same logic we may call religions false because there is no utopia yet.

Comment: @rus9384 no that's BS. plenty of overt goals don't involve anticipated pleasure

Comment: i guess you could say that some goals unconsciously anticipate pleasure. i think that's all you can @rus9384

Comment: Depends on the definition of pleasure. Whatever our reward system tells us to do. Then this is almost infalliable truth.

Comment: @rus9384 how is that different to meaninglessly adding "reward" to any goal

Comment: a higher type is the elite of the elite of the elite of the elite of the elite (minimally), it's not something we encounter

Comment: this question generated some good answers i do not understand your confusion

Comment: any ideas how i can improve this question, or do you just not understand it at all?

Comment: I couldn't understand your last edit:

Perhaps human history is not conducive to the existence of a Beethoven or Goethe (You mean future people of similar character?), and this is the minimum necessary for Nietzsche's archaeology (do you mean genealogy?) to work?

Comment: thanks @MattTurner please upvote! i urge upvoting on answers that have -ve score if they feel meaningful to you

Comment: Consider adding a question to clarify narrow down you query. Something like: "Is there any authors who have examined why Nietzsche's project is a failure?"

Comment: I do not believe in a "single project" in [Nietzsche's philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy_of_Friedrich_Nietzsche) but - if any - it was not the *Übermensch*; more reasonably, it was the critique of Christianity and of current (Western) morality.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the fact that Nietzsche's philosophy is still taught and widely discussed today precludes it from being a complete failure.

I also believe Nietzsche's primary aim/project was the revaluation of values. Though admittedly by Nietzsche's lights that *should* result in more overmen. The great irony that runs through Nietzsche's work is that he is simultaneously rejecting systems of value whilst putting forward his own.  I don't think this irony would have been lost on him, and interpret Nietzsche as offering up his table of values in an effort to urge those concerned with human flourishing to do the same.

There are certainly figures from history that N has written about admirably, Caeser, Goethe, Ceasare Borgia and of course himself.  The concept of the *uber-mensch* has a tendency to be over emphasised in N's work, with N himself devoting relatively little work to the topic. That said, there are certainly traits he admired, and an overview of these can be found in Brian Leiter's Nietzsche on Morality (particularly in chapter 4).  Based on the criteria Leiter identifies (solitariness, responsibility seeking, resilience, life affirming and self reverence) I'm not sure we can definitively say that no such people exist today, figures like Elon Musk spring to mind.

A related concept is discussed extensively in *Zarathustra*, that of the 'last men'. A sort of banal, unimpressive, stilted person that he sees as the inevitable consequence of societies' tendencies to regard happiness as the ultimate aim. This seems to have a degree of relevance when one considers (at least Western) society today.

> Was his mistake to think that mankind can be a going under, or in his specific targeting of morality?

I'm not sure what you mean by the first part, but his targeting of morality was indispensable to his revaluation project for obvious reasons.

Comment: elon musk is not "the meaning of the earth"

Comment: He certainly isn't. I'm not saying he is an example of an overman, but that he exhibits some of the characteristics that Nietzsche identifies with "higher types".

Comment: and human and chimp DNA is 98.8 percent the same

Comment: i find it odd that you regard the last man as an "banal, unimpressive, stilted person" (one would think human history is littered with these) rather than a nihilist

Comment: unless we want to say that that's more inescapable even for elites?

Comment: N's view is that conventional morality (by which he mostly means Christian morals) reduces potentially great people to mediocre ones.  Overly focussed on egalitarian concerns rather than the 'flourishing' of humanity.  This mediocrity of the last men may well be a form of nihilism.

Comment: not sure that you addressed my point. are there more "unimpressive" people or are they only appearing now

Comment: i find it interesting that you frame your "last man" in terms of talent and "higher type" in terms of virtue. hmm... i mean i would have done the inverse

Comment: I think Nietzsche, not me, Nietzsche, would say yes.  Though levels of religious observance, particularly in Europe, have decreased, many of the values with which he took issue are still prevalent today.  It's also worth noting that N believed that 'herd mentality was good for the herd'.  That is, his philosophy was never meant to be open to all, but the select few capable of benefiting from it, and in turn benefitting all of human kind.

Comment: i find that interesting. thanks. i would have assumed the inverse, like i said. i mean, anyone can cultivate "virtue"... few people are truly gifted (this survey of modernism i'm reading says rimbaud and...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85409/discussion-between-matt-turner-and-luke).

Comment: But still, there are non-overmen (they were yet to come at the time of N) who are great artists. Why would N believe that in the end everyone will be a last man **incapable** of arts? I don't know what is the point of overman.